# Using static rnn getting TypeError: Cannot convert value None to a TensorFlow DType

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

First some of my code:

```
...
fc_1 = layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(drop_reshape)  
bi_LSTM_2 = layers.Lambda(buildGruLayer)(fc_1)
...


def buildGruLayer(inputs):

gru_cells = []

gru_cells.append(tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(256))
gru_cells.append(tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(128))
gru_layers = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(gru_cells)

inputs = tf.unstack(inputs, axis=1)

outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
    gru_layers,
    inputs,
    dtype='float32')

return outputs
```

Error I am getting when running static_rnn is:

```
raise TypeError("Cannot convert value %r to a TensorFlow DType." % type_value)
TypeError: Cannot convert value None to a TensorFlow DType.
```

The shape that comes into the Layer in the shape (64,238,256).

Anyone has a clue what the problem could be. I already googled the error but couldn't find anything. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your `inputs` is not None?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you worked it out?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs a solution to this. Its because you need to specify the dtype for the GRUCell, e.g tf.float32

Its default is None which in the documentation defaults to the first dimension of your input data (i.e batch dimension, which in tensorflow is a ? or None)

Check the dtype argument from :
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/GRUCell